# Accessibility in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility

This article https://code.facebook.com/posts/435862739941212/making-react-native-apps-accessible/ talks about AccessibilityInfo API as part of react -native AX APIs, but I can't seem to find that in their repository. Is that not supported anymore?

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/find/master

Answer (score 1):

It's still supported. Check AccessibilityInfo.ios.js: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/cfe003238ab8c5686d185f6ce9e0776eeb4bb729/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo.ios.js